# Weird discrepancy in Density Plot

Tags: plotting

I have the following long Lorentzian function that I have made to be dependent on three parameters (`ω`,`κ2`,`g2`):

```
s[ω_, κ2_, g2_] := (64 g1^2 g2^2 (0.5` + n2) Sqrt[κ2^2])/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))) + (16 g1^2 (0.5` + n1) Sqrt[κ1^2] (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2))) + (4 (0.5` + nm) Γ (16 g2^4 + 8 g2^2 (κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(16 g2^4 (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 8 g1^2 (Γ κ1 - 4 ω^2) + (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) (κ1^2 + 4 ω^2)) + 8 g2^2 ((κ1 κ2 - 4 ω^2) (Γ^2 + 4 ω^2) + 4 g1^2 (Γ κ2 + 4 ω^2)))
```

Plotting `s` as a function of `ω` (with other fixed parameters):

```
Plot[(s[ω, 20, 1] /. {g1 -> 5, κ1 -> 1, Γ -> 1/100, nm -> 300, n1 -> 0.1, n2 -> 0.1}), {ω, -15, 15}, ImageSize -> Automatic, PlotLabel -> {"sbb"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Returns:
[image]

Which is fine. However, I intend to study the behavior of the function as `g1` is varied. So I make the following density plot:

```
DensityPlot[(s[ω, 20, 1] /. {κ1 -> 1, Γ -> 1/100, nm -> 300, n1 -> 0.1, n2 -> 0.1}), {g1, 0, 10}, {ω, -15, 15}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> Medium]
```

But I'm returned with:

[image]
Which make no sense since I should see intensity on the y-axis (`ω`) at `ω = 5` and `ω = -5` as evident in the 2-D plot above (they both were plotted with the same parameters, I'm just varying `g1`). What is going on here? Why is the density plot not showing?

**Edit**: I decided to set my `PlotRange` finitely. Instead of `PlotRange -> All`, I do `PlotRange -> {{0,10},{-15,15}}` (to match my plotting range under `DensityPlot`) and I arrive with: 
[image]

What's going on here? Why are there white spaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever is higher than you plot range will be clipped - that is the white spaces. As you did not specify PlotRange for z value Mathematica clipped it automatically at some low value and everything above is a white space. Before when you specified `PlotRange -> All` it showed all values including very high ones so very low values - most of the plot - were indistinguishable and showed as a uniform background. Read docs on PlotRange for proper specs for 3D cases and maybe also read on ClippingStyle.

Your function has very high values at the origin:

```
Limit[s[0, 20, 1] /. {κ1 -> 1, Γ -> 1/100, nm -> 300, n1 -> 0.1, n2 -> 0.1}, g1 -> 0]
```

> 120199.99999999999`

So you cannot see everything - seeing high values will make low values invisible. So you need to clip at right value to see most of the behavior:

```
Plot3D[s[ω, 20, 
   1] /. {κ1 -> 1, Γ -> 1/100, nm -> 300, 
   n1 -> 0.1, n2 -> 0.1}, {g1, 0, 10}, {ω, -15, 15}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotRange -> {0, 20}]
```

[image]

```
DensityPlot[
 s[ω, 20, 1] /. {κ1 -> 1, Γ -> 1/100, 
   nm -> 300, n1 -> 0.1, n2 -> 0.1}, {g1, 0, 10}, {ω, -15, 15},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotPoints -> 100,
  PlotRangePadding -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> {0, 20}]
```

[image]

Another trick is to log-scale the vertical z-axis:

```
DensityPlot[
 s[ω, 20, 1] /. {κ1 -> 1, Γ -> 1/100, 
   nm -> 300, n1 -> 0.1, n2 -> 0.1}, {g1, 0, 10}, {ω, -15, 15},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]
```

[image]